# JPA persistence.xml share same jar file

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, ejb-3.0, persistence.xml

I'm wondering if I can share the same jar file for several persistence units.. I mean: I have two persistence units described in my persistence.xml file and the entities are not in the same JAR. Entities are in a separated JAR file but, in that one, there are entites for both persistence units. I think I red somewhere that I coould use  tag something like this:
externalEntities.jar#com.mycompany.EntityA
so I could separate them. I tried this solution and it doesn't work. Now I guess that it couldn't be done to package all entities (for two different persistence units) in the same JAR file.

What do yo think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question but did you try to declare your jar with the `jar-file` element. From the spec (section 6.2.1.6):

> One or more JAR files may be specified
>   using the `jar-file` elements instead
>   of, or in addition to the mapping
>   files specified in the `mapping-file`
>   elements. If specified, these JAR
>   files will be searched for managed
>   persistence classes, and any mapping
>   metadata annotations found on them
>   will be processed, or they will be
>   mapped using the mapping annotation
>   defaults defined by this
>   specification. Such JAR files are
>   specified relative to the root of the
>   persistence unit (e.g.,
>   `utils/myUtils.jar`).
>
> ...
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> <persistence-unit name="OrderManagement3">
>   <jar-file>order.jar</jar-file>
>   <jar-file>order-supplemental.jar</jar-file>
> </persistence-unit>
> ```
>
> A persistence unit named
>   `OrderManagement3` is created. Any
>   annotated managed persistence classes
>   found in the root of the persistence
>   unit are added to the list of managed
>   persistence classes. If a
>   `META-INF/orm.xml` file exists, any
>   classes and mapping information
>   contained in it are used as specified
>   above. The `order.jar` and
>   `order-supplemental.jar` files are
>   searched for managed persistence
>   classes and any annotated managed
>   persistence classes found in them
>   and/or any classes  specified in the
>   `orm.xml` files of these jar files are
>   added. The transaction-type, data
>   source and provider are as described
>   above.